# how to use the option '\exshuffle{}' in 'cloze' questions

Tags: r, r-exams

I would like to randomize a cloze question using `\exshuffle{5}` as here:

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=

questions <- solutions <- explanations <- list()

type <-rep("schoice", 2)

questions[[1]]<- letters[1:7]
solutions[[1]]<- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 6))

questions[[2]]<- LETTERS[1:7]
solutions[[2]]<- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 6))



explanations[type=="num"] <- solutions[type=="num"]
explanations[type=="schoice"] <- lapply(solutions[type=="schoice"], 
                                        function(x) ifelse(x, "True", "False"))

solutions[type=="schoice"] <- lapply(solutions[type=="schoice"], mchoice2string)


@

\begin{question}
What is the first letter of ``apple''? ##ANSWER1##

What is the first letter of ``Algeria''? ##ANSWER2##


<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
answerlist(unlist(questions))
@ 


\end{question}


\begin{solution}

<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
answerlist(unlist(explanations))
@


\end{solution}



%% META-INFORMATION
%% \extype{cloze}
%% \exsolution{\Sexpr{paste(solutions, collapse = "|")}}
%% \exclozetype{\Sexpr{paste(type, collapse = "|")}}
%% \exname{question}
%% \exshuffle{5}
```

but importing the question in Moodle I get an error (which I believe is due to `\exshuffle{5}` at the end):

> Error importing question Invalid embedded answers (Cloze) question (One of the answers should have a score of 100% so it is possible to get full marks for this question.).

I would like to understand how to use correctly `\exshuffle{}` within a cloze question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using at least version 2.4-0 of R/exams, then exshuffle within cloze exercises works as intended. Some bugs were fixed to properly support this. In particular, no {solution} environment is necessary anymore to make it work.  (In your case this could simply be dropped because it does not add much value in addition to the exsolution.)